# Last value not stored in Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm following the Mad Lib tutorial on Dash, but I run into the following problem:

Whenever I run the following code, it should store all three of my inputs in the array `answers`, however, it doesn't store the last one. Whenever I output the `answers` array with `showFinal`, it outputs `undefined` where the third answer should be. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w840jpac/) is a jsfiddle, outputting the same problem.

Here's the Javascript:

```
// List of prompts for the user
var prompts = [
    'Type your name',
    'Type an adjective',
    'Type a noun'
   ];

var answers = [];
// Keep track of current prompt we're on
var currentPrompt = 0;

// A function that will call the next prompt
var nextPrompt = function() {
    // if there is a next prompt
    if (currentPrompt < prompts.length) {
      if (currentPrompt != 0) {
        answers.push($('input').val());
      }
        // put first prompt in all html elements with class 
        $('.prompt').html(prompts[currentPrompt] + '<br><input type="text">');
        // move the next prompt into variable currentPrompt 
        currentPrompt = currentPrompt + 1;
    }
    //or else if we're at the end of the array
    else {
        // put a new message into the html.
        showFinal();
    }
}

var showFinal = function() {
  $('.prompt').html(answers[0]+ ' ' + answers[1] + ' ' + answers[2]);
}

// run nextPrompt function when button is clicked
$('button').click(function() {
    nextPrompt();
});

// Show the first prompt as soon as js loads
nextPrompt();
```

Comment: need to push the last input value before `showFinal()`. The prompts are at limit on last answer and they skip over pushing answer, but user just typed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at every step when you click 'Next' it check if there are more prompt messages before saving the current value. But if there are no further prompt messages it skips to showFinal()

You need to push the current value before checking if there are more messages to prompt

```
if (currentPrompt != 0) {
        answers.push($('input').val());
    }
// if there is a next prompt
if (currentPrompt < prompts.length) {
        ....
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w840jpac/1/

Comment: Ah yes, I see I put the `if (currentPrompt != 0) {` in the wrong place. Weird that the system didn't pick it up as a mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this..[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w840jpac/)

```
// List of prompts for the user
var prompts = [
    'Type your name',
    'Type an adjective',
    'Type a noun'];

var answers = [];
// Keep track of current prompt we're on
var currentPrompt = 0;

// A function that will call the next prompt
var nextPrompt = function () {
    // if there is a next prompt
    if (currentPrompt <= prompts.length) {
        if (currentPrompt != 0) {
            console.log($('input').val()+'...');
            answers.push($('input').val());
        }
        // put first prompt in all html elements with class 
        if (currentPrompt != prompts.length) {
        $('.prompt').html(prompts[currentPrompt] + '<br><input type="text">');
        }else{
             showFinal();
        }
        // move the next prompt into variable currentPrompt 
        currentPrompt = currentPrompt + 1;
    }

}

var showFinal = function () {
    $('.prompt').html(answers[0] + ' ' + answers[1] + ' ' + answers[2]);
}

// run nextPrompt function when button is clicked
$('button').click(function () {
    nextPrompt();
});

// Show the first prompt as soon as js loads
nextPrompt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// List of prompts for the user
var prompts = [
    'Type your name',
    'Type an adjective',
    'Type a noun'];

var answers = [];
// Keep track of current prompt we're on
var currentPrompt = 0;

// A function that will call the next prompt
var nextPrompt = function () {
    // if there is a next prompt
    if (currentPrompt > 0) {
            answers.push($('input').val());
    }

    if (currentPrompt < prompts.length) {        
        // put first prompt in all html elements with class 
        $('.prompt').html(prompts[currentPrompt] + '<br><input type="text">');
        // move the next prompt into variable currentPrompt 
        currentPrompt++;
    }
    //or else if we're at the end of the array
    else {
        // put a new message into the html.
        showFinal();
    }
}

var showFinal = function () {
    $('.prompt').html(answers[0] + ' ' + answers[1] + ' ' + answers[2]);
}

// run nextPrompt function when button is clicked
$('button').click(function () {
    nextPrompt();
});

// Show the first prompt as soon as js loads
nextPrompt();
```

I basically moved this section further up in the nextPrompt() function:

```
if (currentPrompt > 0) {
    answers.push($('input').val());
}
```

EDIT:

In response to the comment, I use `> 0` simply because it makes more sense to me. By using `!= 0` you are implicitly implying that `currentPrompt` could be a value less than zero e.g. `-1`. It's subjective, but either way will work for you, it's just a personal thing :)

Comment: You trying to trick me into asking more questions? :P It was `currentPrompt != 0`, not `>` ;)